# How to run a script in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and have no previous programming experience. I want to run a script on python. I have read that I must write the script in a program like notepad++ and save it as a .py file. But what command do I use to run it after that? PLEASE HELP I have looked everywhere and I think the problem is that the question is too basic. I am on windows 7, running python 2.

thanks and sorry if this is not enough information.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't added the Python installation path to your Windows PATH variable yet, Python will be a little harder to run from the command line.

You have two options:

1. Run your script by double clicking on it (might not work).
2. Run your script via command line.

If you want to try it via CLI, press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and run `cmd`.

From the Windows Command Prompt, `cd` into the folder where your Python file resides (Google for a tutorial if you don't know how to) and run `C:\Python27\python.exe your_python_file.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and change the directory to where you saved your script then type: Your_File_Title_here.py (hit enter) and it will run.

Comment: This will work most of the time, but it's common for the .py file extension to become associated with a program other than the Python interpreter in Windows - typically a text editor, i.e. IDLE. In which case this will just open the text editor with the specified .py file.

Answer (score 1):

`python <your_file.py>` is about as standard as it gets.  Be sure that you have Python properly installed on your machine before you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have Python installed in C:\Python27 and you have created a script named test.py and saved it under the same directory.

1. Open command prompt
2. Type: `CD C:\Python27` to go to the Python folder (this is where python.exe is located)
3. Type: `python test.py`  (note: don't type python first, it will activate python interactive mode and it won't work. If you did, just type: `quit()` to quit interactive mode)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is:

1. right click on the .py script
2. select "edit with IDLE" (this opens a Python IDE window for editing / running)
3. press "F5" to run the module (or select "Run Module" from the "Run" drop down menu)